# notifyDataSetOnChange with custom ArrayAdapter and Database

Tags: android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

When I delete a note from the list, it is cancelled, but if **I write another note, in the list once again appear the note that previously cancelled**

I hope someone know how to tell me what the problem is.

Method in **Database** for delete the Note

```
public boolean deleteNote(Nota nota){
    boolean resultDelete = false;
    SQLiteDatabase dbLite = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereClause = "_id = ?";
    String []whereArg = { nota.getId() + "" };
    long a = dbLite.delete("vasca", whereClause, whereArg);
    if (a == -1){
        resultDelete = false;
    }else{
        resultDelete = true;
    }
    dbLite.close();
    return resultDelete;
}
```

**MainActivity**, where I have the ListView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = Database.getInstance(this);
    list = db.listNote();

    // inizializza l'ArrayAdapter
    noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter();
    // setta l'ArrayAdapter
    ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list)).setAdapter(noteAdapter);
```

Here, in the overriden method getView I try:

```
imgRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean removeCheck = db.deleteNote(list.get(position));
                if (removeCheck){
                    System.out.println("RIMOSSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
                    list.remove(getItem(position));

                }else{
                    System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
                }
                noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

**InnerClass of Adapter**

```
class NoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Nota> {

    NoteAdapter() {
        super(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item, list);
    }
    /*
    public void swapItems(ArrayList<Nota> list) {
        this.noteItem = list;
        noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }*/

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        }
        TextView titoloNota = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row);
        TextView bkNota = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row);
        ImageButton imgRemove = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.imgDelete);

        {
            // Settaggio dei colori background e textcolor nel ListView
            if (list.get(position).getColore() == Nota.green) {
                bkNota.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bk_green));
                bkNota.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bk_yellow));
            } else if (list.get(position).getColore() == Nota.yellow) {
                bkNota.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bk_yellow));
                bkNota.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bk_green));
            } else {
                bkNota.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bk_red));
                bkNota.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bk_green));
            }
        }

        // setta il titolo della nota
        titoloNota.setText(list.get(position).getTitolo());

        // listener per la rimozione della nota tramite imagebutton
        imgRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean removeCheck = db.deleteNote(list.get(position));
                if (removeCheck){
                    System.out.println("RIMOSSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
                    noteAdapter.remove(getItem(position));

                }else{
                    System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
                }
                noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: deleting `item` from `database` and calling `notifyDataSetChanged` which will load existing data again its enough. Why you are also removing ` list.remove(getItem(position));`
Also please show us `NoteAdapter` code

Comment: You need to remove it from your adapter, not from your list, post your adapter code and we'll be able to further help you out.

Comment: I tried to eliminate through adapter, but I get same problem..

Comment: I have Edit writing NoteAdapter

Answer (score 0):

AdapterName.this.notifyDatasetChanged();